# Would it makes the kernel level thread clearly preferable to user level thread if system calls is as fast as procedure calls?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, system-calls

Some web searching results told me that **the only deficiency of kernel-level thread** is the slow speed of its management(create, switch, terminate, etc.). It seems that **if the operation on the kernel-level thread is all through system calls, the answer to my question will be true**. However, I've searched a lot to find whether the management of kernel-level thread is all through system call but find nothing. And I always have an instinct that such management should be done by the OS  automatically because only OS knows which thread would be suitable to run at a specific time. So it seems impossible for programmers to write some explicit system calls to manage threads. I'm appreciative of any ideas.

Comment: Please ask your fellow students to do their own homework and stop the continual posting of this question on SO:(

Comment: I have to say that I've done a lot of searching and discussing before I seek help here and my ultimate goal is to learn something new to build up my knowledge. This question may seem too easy for an expert like you, but it could be a challenge for a newcomer like me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Some web searching results told me that the only deficiency of kernel-level thread is the slow speed of its management(create, switch, terminate, etc.).

It's not that simple. To understand, think about what causes task switches. Here's a (partial) list:

- a device told a device driver that an operation completed (some data arrived, etc) causing a thread that was waiting for the operation to unblock and then preempt the currently running thread. For this case you're running kernel code when you find out that a task switch is needed, so kernel task switching is faster.
- enough time passed; either causing an "end of time slice" task switch, or causing a sleeping thread to unblock and preempt. For this case you're running kernel code when you find out that a task switch is needed, so kernel task switching is faster.
- the thread accessed virtual memory that isn't currently accessible, triggering the kernel's page fault handler which finds out that the current task has to wait while the kernel fetches data from from swap space or from a file (if the virtual memory is part of a memory mapped file), or has to wait for kernel to free up RAM by sending other pages to swap space (if virtual memory was involved in some kind of "copy on write"); causing a task switch because the currently running task can't continue. For this case you're running kernel code when you find out that a task switch is needed, so kernel task switching is faster.
- a new process is being created, and its initial thread preempts the currently running thread. For this case you're running kernel code when you find out that a task switch is needed, so kernel task switching is faster.
- the currently running thread asked kernel to do something with a file and kernel got "VFS cache miss" that prevents the request from being performed without any task switches. For this case you're running kernel code when you find out that a task switch is needed, so kernel task switching is faster.
- the currently running thread releases a mutex or sends some data (e.g. using a pipe or socket); causing a thread that belongs to a different process to unblock and preempt. For this case you're running kernel code when you find out that a task switch is needed, so kernel task switching is faster.
- the currently running thread releases a mutex or sends some data (e.g. using a pipe or socket); causing a thread that belongs to the same process to unblock and preempt. For this case you're running user-space code when you find out that a task switch is needed, so in theory user-space task switching is faster, but in practice it can just as easily be an indicator of poor design (using too many threads and/or far too much lock contention).
- a new thread is being created for the same process; and the new thread preempts the currently running thread. For this case you're running user-space code when you find out that a task switch is needed, so in user-space task switching is faster; but only if kernel isn't informed (e.g. so that utilities like "top" can properly display details for threads) - if kernel is informed anyway then it doesn't make much difference where the task switch happens.

For most software (which doesn't use very many threads); doing task switches in the kernel is faster. Of course it's also (hopefully) fairly irrelevant for performance (because time spent switching tasks should be tiny compared to time spend doing other work).

> And I always have an instinct that such management should be done by the OS automatically because only OS knows which thread would be suitable to run at a specific time.

Yes; but possibly not for the reason you think.

Another problem with user-space threading (besides making most task switches slower) is that it can't support global thread priorities without becoming a severe security disaster. Specifically; a process can't know if its own thread is higher or lower priority than a thread belonging to a different process (unless it has information about all threads for the entire OS, which is information that normal processes shouldn't be trusted to have); so user-space threading leads to wasting CPU time doing unimportant work (for one process) when there's important work to do (for a different process).

Another problem with user-space threading is that (for some CPUs - e.g. most 80x86 CPUs) the CPUs are not independent, and there may be power management decisions involved with scheduling. For examples; most 80x86 CPUs have hyper-threading (where a core is shared by 2 logical processors), where a smart scheduler may say "one logical processor in the core is running a high priority/important thread, so the other logical processor in the same core should not run a low priority/unimportant thread because that would make the important work slower"; most 80x86 CPUs have "turbo boost" (with similar "don't let low priority threads ruin the turbo-boost/performance of high priority thread" possibilities); and most CPUs have thermal management (where scheduler might say "Hey, these threads are all low priority, so let's underclock the CPU so that it cools down and can go faster later (has more thermal headroom) when there's high priority/more important work to do!").

> Would it makes the kernel level thread clearly preferable to user level thread if system calls is as fast as procedure calls?

If system calls were as fast as normal procedure calls, then the performance differences between user-space threading and kernel threading would disappear (but all the other problems with user-space threading would remain). However, the reason why system calls are slower than normal procedure calls is that they pass through a kind of "isolation barrier" (that isolates kernel's code and data from malicious user-space code); so to make system calls as fast as normal procedure calls you'd have to get rid of the isolation (effectively turning the kernel into a kind of "global shared library" that can be dynamically linked) but without that isolation you'll have an extreme security disaster. In other words; to have any hope of achieving acceptable security, system calls must be slower than normal procedure calls.

Answer (score -1):

Your basic premise is wrong.  System calls are much slower than procedure calls in almost every interesting architecture.

The perceived cpu throughput is based on pipelining, speculative execution and fetching.   The syscall stops the pipeline, invalidates the speculative execution and halts the speculative fetching, is a store and instruction barrier, and may flush the write fifo.

So, the processor slows down to its ‘spec’ speed around the syscall, accelerating back up until the syscall return, whereupon it does about the exact same thing.

Attempts to optimise this area have given rise to lots of papers named after fictional James Bond organizations, and not conciliatory enough apologies from not embarrassed enough cpu product managers.   Google spectre as an example, then follow the associated links.

*The other cost of syscall*

A bit over 30 years ago, some smart guys wrote a paper about least privilege.  Conceptually, it is a stunner.  The basic premise is that whatever your program is doing, it should do it with the least privilege possible.

If your program is inverting arrays, according to the notion of least privilege, it should not be able to disable interrupts.  Disabling interrupts can cause a very difficult to diagnose system failure.  Simple user code should not have this ability.

The notion of *user* and *kernel* modes of execution evolved from early computer systems, and (with the possible exception of the iax32 / 80286 ) are increasingly showing their inadequacy in the connected computer environment.   At one point in time you could say "this is a single user system"; but the IoT dweebs have made everything multi-user.

*Least privilege* insists that all code should execute with the minimum privilege required to complete the task at hand.  Thus, nothing should be in the kernel that absolutely doesn't need to be.  If you think that is a radical thought, in Ken Thompson's 1977(?) paper on the UNIX kernel he states exactly the same thing.

So no, putting your junk in the kernel just means you have increased the attack surface for no valid reason.  Try to think in terms of exposing minimum risk, it leads to better software and better sleep.

Comment: I see. Your answer does help me build up knowledge about syscall. I know it could be hard to accelerate syscall, and it can never be as fast as a procedure call. Yet I'm not making premise here, it's just an imagined scenario. Could you please help me with my question in such an imagined scenario?

Comment: Communication between separate processes involves task switches. The principle of least privilege suggests that no process should have the privilege needed to interfere with a different process' tasks and therefore no process should be allowed to do these task switches. Given that kernel "must" (according to principle of least privilege) do these task switches, there is no sane reason why kernel can't/shouldn't do all task switches (and avoid duplicating task switching in every single process and increasing attack surface).